# Access asset file based on current context in play framework 2.3

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

How can I return an Asset file based on user permission.
means that I want show page based on user access level.

with using this method , current context is not available:

```
public play.api.mvc.Action<AnyContent> index() {
    try {
        if (securityService.getCurrentSession(Controller.ctx()) == null) {
            return Assets.at("/public", "/main.html", false);
        }else
            return Assets.at("/public", "/index/index.html", false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Assets.at("/public", "/index/index.html", false);
    }
}
```

due to this error:

```
There is no HTTP Context available from here.
```

and using this method return asset as download file:

```
public Result index() {
    try {
        if (securityService.getCurrentSession(Controller.ctx()) == null) {
            return Results.ok(Play.application().getFile("/public/index/index.html"));
        }else
            return Results.ok(Play.application().getFile("/public/main.html"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Results.ok(Play.application().getFile("/public/index/index.html"));
    }
}
```

How can I show index page based on user privilege?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `ok(java.io.File)` method you can use [ok(java.io.File, boolean)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html#ok(java.io.File,%20boolean)) where second parameter specify result is inline or attachement.

like this:

```
public Result index() {
    try {
        if (securityService.getCurrentSession(Controller.ctx()) == null) {
            return Results.ok(Play.application().getFile("/public/index/index.html"), true);
        } else
            return Results.ok(Play.application().getFile("/public/main.html"), true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Results.ok(Play.application().getFile("/public/index/index.html"), true);
    }
}
```